# Deprecate for external users, but allow for me?

Tags: rust

I found [Can I mark a function as deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757914/can-i-mark-a-function-as-deprecated) and use it in my own crate:

```
pub enum FooParams {
    #[deprecated(since = "0.0.1", note = "use `FooParams::New` instead")]
    Old,
    New,
}

pub struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(p: FooParams) -> Foo {
        match p {
            FooParams::Old => {}
            FooParams::New => {}
        }
        Foo
    }
}
```

This works for external crates and warns them to not use `FooParams::Old`.
It also applies to my crate, generating annoying warnings. Is there any way to disable this warning?

I tried this but the warning is still present:

```
#[allow(deprecated)]
FooParams::Old => {}
```

Comment: I don't think attaching attributes to expressions (or sub expression parts) currently does anything in Rust. Have you tried attaching the `#[allow(deprecated)]` attribute to the function instead?

Comment: @WesleyWiser It works, but real function use code from other crates, is it suppress warnings from them about deprecation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the attribute to the match statement:

```
impl Foo {
    pub fn new(p: FooParams) -> Foo {
        #[allow(deprecated)]
        match p {
            FooParams::Old => {}
            FooParams::New => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Other usages of `Old` in your crate will continue to have the warning.

Comment: But what about dependicies of my crate? If I use in `fn new` functionality from other crates, is this suppress warning about other, not only `FooParams::Old`?

Comment: @user1244932 I don't think I'm fully understanding your question. The attribute only prevents the warning message for the *single* expression that it's on. People using your crate will never get a deprecation warning from calling *your* usage of a deprecated function.