# How can I display a compiler warning upon function invocation?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, static-analysis

I've got a function I want to export in my module so people can use it. However, in ≈95% of cases, using it is a bad idea.

```
/// Check whether foo is a metasyntactic variable.
/// 
/// **Using this function is a mistake.** This function is slow,
/// since checking widgets is an extremely expensive operation.
/// You should be keeping track of what's what, and ideally will
/// never need to use this function.
/// 
/// If you _do_ need to use this function, please consider a refactor.
pub fn test_widget(foo: String) -> bool {
    false
}
```

It's mostly around for documentation and testing purposes. However, since there's the ≈5% of cases where such a thing may be genuinely useful, I want to keep it around.

I *don't* want people accidentally using it, so I want to make invocation of the function cause a compiler warning (unless they explicitly override it with [`allow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#lint-check-attributes) or something). How can I do this?

Comment: And no, I can't just rely on the type system keeping track of this; in the real example, this is testing the validity of items that can expire with time (and certain mutations) that should be handled by the database. Assume that the premise of the question is valid, unless I'm missing something _really_ obvious.

Answer (score 7):

You can mark the function as [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30757914/1896169):

```rust
// Consider summarizing this and linking to the docs, rather than putting the
// entire message here.
#[deprecated(note=
    "**Using this function is a mistake.**
This function is slow,
since checking widgets is an extremely expensive operation.
You should be keeping track of what's what, and ideally will
never need to use this function.

If you _do_ need to use this function, please consider a refactor.")]
pub fn test_widget(foo: String) -> bool {
    /// Check whether foo is a metasyntactic variable.
    false
}
```

If the user uses the function, they get a warning:

```
warning: use of deprecated item 'test_widget': **Using this function is a mistake.**
This function is slow,
since checking widgets is an extremely expensive operation.
You should be keeping track of what's what, and ideally will
never need to use this function.

If you _do_ need to use this function, please consider a refactor.
```

But they can turn it off with `#[allow(deprecated)]`:

```
#[allow(deprecated)]
test_widget("Hello, World!".to_string()); // no warning
```

[Playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=405cbccf3b5bdeb873dafc3f582d4e56)

Comment: This answer works, but I don't really like it because it semantically misuses the `deprecated` attribute. It may be the only currently available method, however.

Comment: @Shepmaster I agree. I'll wait a little before accepting it… but this does seem to accomplish what I want, and the semantic error is minor.

Comment: @Justin Should the deprecated attribute go above or below the doc comment?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 it doesn't matter the order; it's a matter of style (doc comments become `#[doc]` attributes). I'd put it after.

Comment: @Shepmaster [may I abuse another attribute](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec44574f19d6039421c7460c1c4add40)? :D

Comment: @mcarton I rather like it actually.

Answer (score 7):

The `must_use` seems to be fitting here and allows to specify a custom message:

```rust
#[must_use = "Calling this function is a bad idea"]
pub struct BadIdeaFunction(bool);

impl BadIdeaFunction {
    pub fn i_acknowledge_calling_this_function_is_a_bad_idea(self) -> bool {
        self.0
    }
}

/// Check whether foo is a metasyntactic variable.
///
/// **Using this function is a mistake.** This function is slow,
/// since checking widgets is an extremely expensive operation.
/// You should be keeping track of what's what, and ideally will
/// never need to use this function.
///
/// If you _do_ need to use this function, please consider a refactor.
pub fn test_widget() -> BadIdeaFunction {
    BadIdeaFunction(false)
}

fn main() {
    test_widget(); // gives a warning, but the next one doesn't

    test_widget().i_acknowledge_calling_this_function_is_a_bad_idea();
}
```

This creates a warning with the custom message:

```
warning: unused `BadIdeaFunction` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:23:5
   |
23 |     test_widget();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
   = note: Calling this function is a bad idea
```

Comment: This is a funny solution, but it prevents people from using the function normally (as opposed to just complaining at them).

Comment: Reminds me of aptitude's prompt that asks the user to type "Yes, I am aware this is a very bad idea" (capitalization and all) when one tries to uninstall packages that will break the system.

Comment: @trentcl You're right! Autocompletion makes this too easy to bypass! [We need to use capitalization to make it an actual challenge to get right!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb66ecd1fe3142a9e23404bd5f0015d4)

Comment: A lot of people have upvoted this answer very quickly. Could somebody explain why this is a good answer? I don't understand.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure, but I wouldn't be too surprised to see a pattern like this in the wild, although with a less ridiculous name.

Comment: I find this a perfectly reasonable solution to the problem posed. If the solution is a bit silly, maybe it's because the problem is a bit silly. If the problem is reasonable, both this and the other answer are reasonable solutions. You might not want to use it in your particular case but that doesn't make it not a good answer.