# How to emit a compiler warning in Rust?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

In a Rust program, it is possible to emit a compiler error and halt the translation machinery, for example:

```rust
macro_rules! a {
  ($name:ident) => {println!("{}", name)};
  ($exp:expr) => {compile_error!("Do not use an expression.")};
}
```

Is there a similar macro to emit a compile-time warning? I'm using the `syn` crate and have through the documentation, but couldn't find any reference.

The only thing I can find [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/?search=warn) are a series of nightly-only APIs, which won't work for my use case because I can't use a nightly release.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741004/how-can-i-display-a-compiler-warning-upon-function-invocation/56798246#56798246) answer you question? As far as I know, abusing those attributes is the only way at the moment.